# How create admin login on php website?

Tags: php, authentication, administration

My registration page and login form is working fine. If any member register and then login, user come to member.php page. member page has their profile information which is only for members. Now i want to create an admin login in which admin will redirect to admin.php page. This page has all information
like:
about how many user register (done) 
all other admin task(done)

I have done my admin pages but i dont know how to authorise admin login and password, if i use those then it will take me to admin area.

Here is my code of login form

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login-exec.php">
  <table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="112"><b>User id (Email-id)</b></td>
      <td width="188"><input name="user_email" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Password</b></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

code for login-exec.php

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server



    //Select database
    ----something----

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $user_email = clean($_POST['user_email']);
    $pwd = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($user_email == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($pwd == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login-form.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND password='$pwd' ";

    if ($user_email= )

    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $customer = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_id'] = $customer['id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_fname'] = $customer['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_lname'] = $customer['last_name'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: member-index.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login-failed.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an extra field in your database for all members including admin to set user permission to store user permissions.
If that field is admin you can have admin area for that user else if it is member than you can go for member area.

Comment: Can you guys provide me user level example please . I am new to php and i am doing my reserch on google and reach this stage

Comment: when you register a user, add a field whether it is an admin user or not.And while checking for password for member check that field to have value for member and same way do check for admin also in your query.

Comment: no, because there is only one admin who going to manage this website. members can only visit to their member pages. So i cant put admin in registration form. for example if i want xxx@abc.com and password 12345,  want to use for admin login , so is there any way i can use these values s on above code.

Comment: Then go for the solution as answered by Mike.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an Extra Part of your Database index to classify permissions IE: like a "level" permission, and then check that level. AKA: If level is above 3 or something, allow access to auto access an Admin page.

Comment: Can you guys provide me user level example please . I am new to php and i am doing my reserch on google and reach this stage.

Comment: i dont have any idea to solve my this issue, Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So to rephrase the problem, you've grabbed code from somewhere (here perhaps: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=314604), and now you want to change its behavior to also allow admin users.  The best advice I have is to understand the code you are using first.

Look for the line `header("Location: member-index.php");` that is the line that redirects the user to the member-index page. Since you have indicated you don't want to do it properly with a database field, you can hardcode a test for the value of $user_email; if it is admin@blah, then you can set a special Session variable say, 'SESS_isadmin', and redirect to a different page instead.  That new page can test the 'SESS_isadmin' value to make sure the user is logged in; if they are not, you can redirect them to the login page.

Short of actually writing the code for you, that's as "user-level" as it gets. :)

A word of caution: do not use this approach to coding for actual production-level code; learning about a programming language this way is fine, but there are a lot more things to consider before you put this stuff out in the wild.